# Obtener valor de un Session en Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo una variable de sesion

> Session["Producto"]

Y quiero obtener el valor de esta en Javascript de esta forma:

```
$(function () {
    debugger;
    var name = '<%= Session["Producto"] %>';
    alert(name);
});
```

Pero lo que esta pasando es que me imprime literalmente el string **name**, no el valor que contiene la sesión.
Digamos en el alert aparece esto:

> 

Tambien probe con:

> '<%= Session["Producto"].ToString() %>'
>
> '@Session["Producto"]';

Y no funcionaron tampoco. Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que estas intentando obtener un valor del servidor (c#) desde javascript, del lado del cliente, no vas a poder, deberías guardar la variable en un hidden, y luego obtenerla desde javascript

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= Session["Producto"].ToString() %>" id="mivariable">
```

y para obtenerla con jquery

```
$(function () {
debugger;
var name = $("#mivariable").val()
alert(name);
```

});

Comment: Ahora si, estaba confundido, pense que se podia obtener esa variable desde el cliente. Muchas gracias,

Comment: Excelente me funciono, con PHP también.

Answer (score 0):

De esa forma no es posible acceder a los valores de variables de sesión del servidor. Para ello yo tengo una solución. Creo una función pública en el servidor que recibe un parámetro "sesion" (por ejemplo) y devuelve el valor de ese parámetro (que sería el valor de la variable de sesión). Desde Javascript se puede llamar a funciones en el servidor directamente (al menos yo las he probado de esta forma directa con un parámetro).
Por ejemplo:

En el servidor:

La función siguiente está creada dentro de un módulo de clase. Para llamarla desde Javascript es necesario declarar una clase que herede la clase que contiene la función. Más abajo veremos que la instancia de la clase heredada del ejemplo se llama "Cp".

```
public class Claseprincipal 
{
public string Varsesion(string variable) {
      
        string v;
        v = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["" + variable + ""]);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Después mostramos, por ejemplo, un log con la cadena de la variable de sesión obtenida en Javascript en el cliente desde el servidor con la función anterior "Varsesion"

[en el cliente]

```
console.log("Importación desde mi conservatorio realizada por " +
                "el profesor/a: " + "<%=Cp.Varsesion("Profesor")%>")
```

Para poder usar la función en Javascript es necesario heredar la clase contenedora de la función. Esto se puede hacer añadiendo esa declaración en el bloque de código de la clase Page (C#). De este modo:

```
 public partial class Alumnos : Page
    {
        public class CP : Claseprincipal { }
        public CP Cp = new CP { };
}
```

CP es heredada de Claseprincipal. Después obtenemos una instancia nueva de esa clase (Cp) que es la que se emplea para utilizar la función Varsesion.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta anterior que propuse para obtener el valor de variables de sesión del servidor desde Javascript no es una solución para todos los casos. En la pruebas que he hecho el valor se recupera solo en el momento de carga de la página. Esto sirve para variables de sesión que desde el inicio de nuestra sesión se establecen de forma permanente. Luego si son variables de sesión con valor dinámico ese método no es efectivo.
Propongo una forma que llevo tiempo usando que soluciona el acceso a variables de sesión del servidor con valores cambiantes. Para ello uso instrucciones de iteración para comprobar si los valores cambian y también un archivo de texto (.txt) para guardar en el servidor el valor de la variable buscada. Este archivo debe estar creado previamente en el servidor (o también crearse dinámicamente). En este ejemplo lo aporto en el servidor creado manualmente.

El código es el siguiente:

SERVIDOR
En una página que recibe la solicitud. En este caso es Respuestaajax.aspx

```
public void Respuestaaj()
        {
     if (Request["parametro"] == "session")
        
        StreamWriter oSW = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/txt/txt_valor_buscado.txt");
        
                        oSW.WriteLine("");
                        oSW.Flush();
                        oSW.Close();
        
        
        StreamWriter oSW2 = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/txt/txt_valor_buscado.txt");
                       
                        oSW2.WriteLine(Session[Request["valor"]]);
                        oSW2.Flush();
                        oSW2.Close();
                    }
}
```

EN EL CLIENTE
Esta es la función que inicia el proceso desde el ciente

```
function varsesionserver(nombrevariable) {
        //esta función devuelve el valor de la variable de sesión del servidor ASP.NET
        //especificada en nombrevariable. 
    
        var te = "";          //inicialmente es "", así sabremos si ha cambiado después
        do {
            te = valoresporajax("session", nombrevariable);      
        } while (te == "");
    
        return te;
    }
```

La función anterior emplea otra función Javascript que es la encargada de hacer los envíos Ajax para que en el servidor se escriba el valor de la variable de sesión en el archivo de texto y se devuelva ese valor. La iteración garantiza en esta función que mientras ese valor no sea distinto de "" no se obtendrá el resultado final.

Código de la función valoresporajax de Javascript

```
function valoresporajax(parametro, valor) {  
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "Respuestaajax.aspx", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("parametro=" + parametro +
        "&valor=" + valor);    

    //obteniendo desde el archivo .txt el valor buscado de la variable
    //se declara un nuevo objeto para conectar
    var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp2.open("GET", "txt/txt_valor_buscado.txt", false);
    xhttp2.send(); //se inicia la solicitud
    var resultado = xhttp2.responseText;        //la respuesta con el valor del parámetro buscado
    return resultado;     //la función devuelve finalmente el valor del parámetro buscado que corresponde a la variable de sesión
}
```

Este procesamiento funciona perfectamente cada vez que se requiere el valor de la variable de sesión desde el cliente. El envío por Ajax de la solicitud a la página que va a procesarla (en este ejemplo Respuestaajax.aspx) contiene los parámetros "parámetro" y "valor". Si el primero es "session" el método Respuestaaj() escribe en el archivo de texto el valor de la variable de sesión con el nombre del parámetro "valor". Ese dato es examinado en la iteración de la función varsesionserver desde su invocación hasta que sea distinto de "", momento en el que se devuelve.

Para usar en cualquier punto de nuestro código Javascript para obtener la variable de sesión basta con escribir:

```
var tp = varsesionserver("nuevotxtprof");
```

En este ejemplo obtenemos en la variable tp el valor devuelto por varsesionserver que será el de la variable de sesión del servidor denominada "nuevotxtprof".
En algunas ocasiones uso iteraciones en el servidor para comprobar el valor de la variable de sesión, lo que resulta útil para dar vía libre a posteriores procesos que podrían haberse iniciado desde el cliente.

En cuanto al tiempo que se emplea para obtener la respuesta he de decir que se trata en muchos casos de menos de un segundo. En la mayoría de los casos es así. En la iteración de la función Javascript en cada una de las pasadas se producen dos envíos Ajax. Uno de envío a la página y otro para recibir el dato de la variable desde el .txt.

Hay que tener en cuenta que un envío Ajax asíncrono tarda un tiempo impredecible en realizarse completamente y por lo tanto si en las líneas de código Javascript que siguen al envío necesitamos el valor obtenido desde el servidor es muy probable que aún ese valor no esté disponible en el cliente. No ha habido tiempo suficiente para el envío al servidor, proceso en el mismo y proceso en el cliente para obtener el valor del archivo de texto.  Para evitar errores de recursos insuficiente es conveniente poner un tiempo de espera entre cada iteración. De este modo:

```
function varsesionserver(nombrevariable) {
                //esta función devuelve el valor de la variable de 
                //sesión 
                //del servidor ASP.NET
                //especificada en nombrevariable. 
            
                var te = "";          //inicialmente es "", así 
                                      //sabremos 
                                     //si 
                                     //ha cambiado después
              do {
                    te = valoresporajax("session", nombrevariable); 
                   sleep(200);     
                } while (te == "");
            
                return te;
        }
```

La función **sleep**  aplica un tiempo de espera en milisegundos al código Javascript y debe estar disponible en nuestra página o en un archivo relacionado. Se puede usar cualquier otra opción que dé el mismo resultado.

Comment: Hola! Siendo estas tus **primeras respuestas**, te recomiendo que coloques todas las soluciones en una sola respuesta y en todo caso menciones en alguna leyenda de **Actualización** si necesitaras aclarar que agregaste algo nuevo.  Seria conveniente que respondes específicamente lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Hola! Pues sí, lo haré así. Gracias.